# Why is UIPopoverController so tall?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I have the following code to open a 320px x 320px `UIPopoverController`, but for some reason the popover is much taller than it should be - about twice the height that I specified (320px).

What's gone wrong?

```
    colorPicker = [[RSColorPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 320.0, 320.0)];
    [colorPicker setDelegate:self];
    [colorPicker setBrightness:1.0];
    [colorPicker setCropToCircle:YES];
    [colorPicker setBrightness:1.0];
    [colorPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIColor * aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.803 green:0.4 blue:0.144 alpha:1];
    [colorPicker setSelectionColor:aColor];

    UIView *newview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 320.0, 320.0)];
    [newview addSubview:colorPicker];

    UIViewController *newviewcontroller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [newviewcontroller setView:newview];

    UIPopoverController *newpopover =
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newviewcontroller];

    newpopover.delegate = self;
    [self.colourController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
    self.colourController = newpopover;

    [self.colourController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(149, 540, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `popoverContentSize` on the view controller being presented in the popover. You are setting it on the wrong view controller.

```
newpopover.delegate = self;
self.colourController = newpopover;
[self.colourController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
```

You were doing these last two lines out of order.